# AJAX no data showing up from server request

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I am tryng to get AJAX to post to a seperate php file and then have that data put into a div. The ultimate goal will be to set up a long poll for auto updating, but baby steps.

So nothing shows up in the div when the page is loaded. I checked the console and the ajax does send the 'initiate' POST but it doesn't seem to receive anything back except headers.

*FIXED* whole time i was missing curly brackets. Thanks for all the syntax help guys.

here is the code

Php file that ajax calls

```
<?php
require "dbc.php";

    $function = $_POST['function'];



    switch($function)
    case('initiate'):
    $search="SELECT * FROM Feedtest ORDER BY id DESC";
    $request = mysql_query($search);
    $mostrecent= mysql_fetch_array($request);
    $mostrecentid = $mostrecent['id'];
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($mostrecentid);
     break; 


    case('update'):
    $search="SELECT * FROM Feedtest ORDER BY id DESC";
    $request = mysql_query($search);
    $update= mysql_fetch_array($request);
    $updateid = $update['id'];
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($updateid);
     break;          
?>
```

The page where the call is made

```
<div id="datacheck"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function()  {
     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'feedupdate.php',
          data: {function: 'initiate'},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(msg) {
              $('#datacheck').html(msg);
          }

        });
  }); // document ready

</script>
```

Comment: data: {function: 'initiate'},

Comment: no apostrophe to function?

Comment: yes and comma in the end

Answer (score 4):

You forgot `,` here

```
data: {function: 'initiate'}, // here
datatype: "json",
```

also

```
'function': 'initiate'
```

should be

```
function: 'initiate'
```

**function** is reserved word in javascript, so you need to change that to other name as well.

Comment: @user2444298 use `error: function(msg) {
              alert(msg);
          }`

Answer (score 0):

"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

you were missed ,

```
data: {function: 'initiate'},
datatype: "json",
```

Comment: ok the response is not empty i checked and it should be 4 but nothing happens.

Comment: show me your response, for instance, your response looks like this {'test':'test val'} then you can get the value as msg.test.

Comment: they are all just response headers when looking at the console but the query should return 4.